# Expected a Declaration(C++)

Tags: c++

I don't now what i missed but Visual Studio hits for on 12 row and says "Expected a declaration" and "Expected a ";"" at the end of code. 
There's a code:

```
#include <string>
#include <math.h>  

using namespace std;

class DigPow
{
public:
  static int digPow(int n, int p)
  {
    int tmpnumb = 0;
    string temp = to_string(n);
    for (int i = 0; i<temp.length();i++)
    {
      tmpnumb += pow (temp[i],p);
      p++;
    }
    for (int i = 1; ;i++)
    {
      if (tmpnumb*i == n)
      {
        return i;
      }      
      if (tmpnumb*i > n)
      {
        return -1;
      }

    }

  }
};
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qiSfIzcyoGIhZnz5).

Comment: You do not have a main() function. Also, include <cmath> not <math.h>. And beware that length() returns size_t and not int. One is an unsigned integer, the other is a signed integer.

Comment: in the code you posted line 12 is `string temp = to_string(n);` is it also line 12 in the original code? Please include the full error message

Comment: Why write a class `DigPow` which only contains one static function `digPow`. Why not just write the function and drop the class? In C++ you don't have to put everything in a class. BTW like everyone else I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: If a problem that seemingly doesn't exist persist, it might be a bad day for the Visual Studio Intellisense. Try right clicking on the source code -> `Rescan` (at the bottom) -> `Rescan File` or `Rescan Solution`. Also you might want to `Rebuild`.